# Print array elements AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I would print a string with Angular variables.

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('monApp',[]);
app.controller('Controleur',function($scope){$scope.infos={
    "prenom": "Jean",
    "nom": "Dupont",
    "dateNaissance": new Date(1991,11,1)
    };
}


</script>
```

I would like to print Hello Jean Dupont  born on  "1991-11-30T23:00:00.000"
I have tried many ways to print finded on web but no result.

```
<body data-ng-app="monApp" class ="ng-scope">
    <div data-ng-controller="Controleur" class ="ng-scope" ><p>Hello {{prenom}} {{scope.infos[1], born on {{scope.infos[2]}}</p></div>

</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$scope.infos` is a `Object` not `Array`, you should select to it with `$scope.infos['propertyName']` or `$scope.infos.propertyName`

View:

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="Controller">
    <p>Hello {{infos.prenom + ' ' + infos.nom + ', born on ' + infos.dateNaissance}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('Controller', function($scope) {
  $scope.infos = {
    "prenom": "Jean",
    "nom": "Dupont",
    "dateNaissance": new Date(1991,11,1)
    };
});
```

See example: [Here](http://codepen.io/huychau/pen/yJNmGL)

Answer (score 2):

you associate your data with scope `infos` variable, so a proper use would be:

```
<div data-ng-controller="Controleur" class ="ng-scope" ><p>Hello {{infos.prenom}} {{infos.nom}}, born on {{infos.dateNaissance}}</p></div>
```

**tip**: if your don't intend to change your data after inserting it, you can make use of Angular's *one-time bindings*, which will improve performance

```
<div data-ng-controller="Controleur" class ="ng-scope" ><p>Hello {{::infos.prenom}} {{::infos.nom}}, born on {{::infos.dateNaissance}}</p></div>
```

Comment: I get `Hello {{infos.prenom}} {{infos.nom}}, born on {{infos.dateNaissance}}`

Comment: @unfoudev that's probably because you have syntax error in your javascript, you forgot about `);` at the end of your code